# Is DROP/ADD UNIQUE constraint in ALTER TABLE atomic?

Tags: mysql, index, alter-table, unique-constraint

I have a `UNIQUE` constraint of a number of fields on a table. Image that I want to change the fields in this constraint (remove one field). Normally I would do something like:

```
DROP INDEX unique_name ON table_name;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_name ON table_name (field1, field2, ...);
```

But these are two statements, and after executing the first one there will be no `UNIQUE` constraint anymore, so any `INSERT` may potentially break the constraint, until new `UNIQUE` is created.

There is another way to do that:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP INDEX unique_name, 
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_name UNIQUE (field1, field2, ...);
```

This is one statement. The questions is: will this statement perform an atomic operation? By atomic I mean that there is no *time window* when there is no `UNIQUE` constraint at all.

Comment: Why not put the whole statement inside a transaction?

Comment: @dfundako DDL like `ALTER TABLE` cause an implicit commit in MySQL. There is no point or way) having them inside a transaction.

Comment: @Alexander I think the answer is yes. But why not do the 2 alter in the opposite order to be sure that there is always at least one UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ It just won't work, because I need to remove one field from UNIQUE and the constraint will be broken then. It will work, if I need to add a new field only.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Updated the post to clarify, that I need to remove the field.

Comment: I don't see any field (aka column) removing in the code you posted.

Comment: In my real database the UNIQUE was on 4 fields, and I need to have it only on 3 fields.

Comment: If you choose a different name for the constraint then you can first add the new UNIQUE constraint. Then remove the old one. Nothing difficult with that option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the official [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) documentation, there should be no issue with such an operation and there is no window when there is no `UNIQUE` constraint at all. See (emphasis mine):

> Storage, Performance, and Concurrency Considerations
>
> In most cases, ALTER TABLE makes a temporary copy of the original table. **MySQL waits for other operations that are modifying the table, then proceeds.** It incorporates the alteration into the copy, deletes the original table, and renames the new one. While `ALTER TABLE` is executing, the original table is readable by other sessions (with the exception noted shortly). **Updates and writes** to the table **that begin after the `ALTER TABLE` operation begins are stalled** until the new table is ready, then are automatically redirected to the new table without any failed updates. The temporary copy of the original table is created ...

---

Of course nothing forbids you from doing the operation in two steps (but this will probably be less efficient).

- first add the new `UNIQUE` constraint (with a different name):

  ```
  ALTER TABLE table_name
      ADD CONSTRAINT unique_name_2 
      UNIQUE (field1, field2, ...) ;
  ```
- the delete the old one:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE table_name
      DROP INDEX unique_name ;
  ```

This allows a small window where you'll have both constraints but again no time where none of them is there.